# why does my movie clip changes its position after playing it

Tags: actionscript-3

I have my movie clip and it's in the original position and pressing a button, the movie clip will play, but when I want a desired position for my movie clip after playing it, the movie clip is not following it can you answer please?

the code for my button is:

btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.Click, button);

```
function button(event:MouseEvent):void{
      char1.gotoAndPlay(2); //plays the movieclip of char1
      char1.x=597.45; //after playing it, the movieclip should go to this coordinate
      char1.y=53.60;
}
```

char1 is on the position of char1.x=269.5 and char1.y=459.55.
but when i press the button the movieclip is played in char1.x=597.45 and char1.y=53.60 not on his original position. how can i play it on the original position and after playing it, it will go to my desired coordinate?

Comment: You need to provide more details, specifically code related to this issue. Right now, we have absolutely no idea what you are talking about.

Comment: @JoshJanusch sir here is my code sorry i cant explain well im not good good in english sir..sorry for that! help me sir thanks im a newbie in  as3!

Comment: So you DO want it to move, but not until the `MovieClip` has finished playing, correct?

Comment: i want it to move after the movie clip has been played is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, `MovieClip` doesn't support `Event.COMPLETE`. Instead, you listen for `Event.ENTER_FRAME` and check if the current frame is the last frame

```
mc.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrameHandler);
function enterFrameHandler(e:Event):void {
    if (mc.currentFrame == mc.totalFrames) {
        // movie clip is complete
        mc.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterFrameHandler); // runs each frame, so make sure you remove the listener
    }
}
```